# Why my GEB script fails when I use a seperate helper function?

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I was trying to run a GEB test using Gradle; It works fine if I run everything from a method but fails if I use a helper function:

Scenario 1 that works:

```
def "Select ORG Unit and save the invoice and Delete it"() {            
    when: "We click arrivals drop-down link"
        waitFor { inprogtoArrivals.isDisplayed() }

    then: "Click on the Arrivals Tab"
        waitFor { $('#arrivalsTab').find("a").click() }

        Browser.drive {
                go driver.currentUrl
            }
        waitFor { createInvoice.click() }
}
```

Scenario 2 that doesn't work:

```
def uploadInvoice() {

    when: "We click arrivals drop-down link"
        waitFor { inprogtoArrivals.isDisplayed() }

    then: "Click on the Arrivals Tab"
        waitFor { $('#arrivalsTab').find("a").click() }
}

def "Select ORG Unit and save the invoice and Delete it"() {            
    when:           
        uploadInvoice()
        Browser.drive {
                go driver.currentUrl
            }
    then:
        waitFor { createInvoice.click() }
}
```

Here, it can't handle `uploadInvoice()` and fails. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Why are you using `Browser.drive {}` blocks inside of your specs? Using plain `go driver.currentUrl` should work without any need to wrap it in any `drive {}` blocks.

Comment: If something fails for you it's usually good to include the stacktrace - that way it is way easier to help out.

Comment: thanks for the tips in your first comment. I was totally unaware of that!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `when:` and `then:` blocks inside of a helper methods because these blocks are what Spock uses to differentiate between feature (test) methods and regular methods. The fact that you used these blocks means that `uploadInvoice()` is a test.

Comment: I don't know whether there is a rule that I can not use when: and then: inside a helper function but I have used at least 50 helper functions with when: and then:; and they worked fine for me!